# Ok button is not working on QDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I'm working on an app in C++/Qt I have used the design tool to design a Qdialog box.

The Dialog box is defined as below.

c++ file

```
#include "dialogwarning.h"
#include "ui_dialogwarning.h"

DialogWarning::DialogWarning(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogWarning)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

DialogWarning::~DialogWarning()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

header file

```
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class DialogWarning;
}

class DialogWarning : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DialogWarning(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DialogWarning();

private:
    Ui::DialogWarning *ui;
};
```

The source use it as below:

```
WarningDialog = new DialogWarning();
QLabel *label = new QLabel("File/Folder name already exist", WarningDialog);
label->setGeometry(WarningDialog->rect().center().x() - label->rect().width()/2,
                   WarningDialog->rect().center().y() - label->rect().height()*2,
                   WarningDialog->rect().width(),
                   WarningDialog->rect().height());
WarningDialog->exec();
```

I'm using exec instead of show because the exec primitive allow me to be stucked inside the dialog until a press on the "Ok" button.

What is strange is that the OK button is not working. I do not need any specific behavior just wait the OK press to continue to run the code.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the code that creates the QPushButton and connects it to a slot?

Comment: @kiss-o-matic thanks you're right forget to do it.... sorry I'm should take a nap

Answer (score 0):

i'm not quite sure assuming u have connected everything. could be that the application is frozen.

why not put the calculation in a different thread and connect the same signal that shows the dialog to thread pause.

the signal of the ok pushbutten should be connected to close the dialog and thread resume...